# How to convert dates? תשכ'ה

Tags: hebrew

תשכ'ה

And generally, what is the system here?  (I took a quick survey of the internet, and did not find a way to parse these dates from letters to roman numbers.)

Comment: The gematria of the letters is 400, 300, 20, 5 for a total of 725.

Comment: https://www.jewishgen.org/Infofiles/m_calint.htm?gclid=EAIaIQobChMItfCTtaaO9QIVoRvUAR3vtASUEAAYASAAEgIMsvD_BwE

Comment: are you looking for "gematria", which is the numerical equivalent of Hebrew letters? Once you have that, you add up the values. Years are typically written with the "thousands place" missing, and implied from context. So "725" is most likely "5725" (unless you know otherwise from context). To convert to "regular" years, subtract 3760 (equivalent in the Jewish calendar to the year 0) to get 1965.